# Properties of the degree of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I read in some text that if there are two polynomial functions f(x) and g(x) having degrees m and n  respectively, then those follow following rules:(one of them was)

- $f(x) \pm g(x)$ is a polynomial of degree  $\le \max$ {$n,m$}.

Please can anyone help me with this, I know it seems easy but for now my mind isn't working.

Comment: [ SHOUTS IN $\LaTeX$. ]

Comment: Many people here regard the use of all capitals to be the equivalent of shouting, and therefore find it rude.

Comment: To your question.. Suppose $m≤n$ and write $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$ and $g(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n b_ix^i$.  (why can we do that?)  Then $f(x)\pm g(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n(a_i\pm b_i)x^i$ clearly has degree $≤n$.  To see why we have $≤$ instead of $=$ let $f(x)=x^2+x+1$ and $g(x)=x^2$,  so $f(x)-g(x)=2x+1$.

Comment: Just try it out with some concrete polynomials. Take some arbitrary polynomials and add/subtract them. Then you should see what happens.

Comment: If you write out the general forms of the polynomials and use the definition of the degree of a polynomial, you should have no problem to show this property.

Comment: If you wish to avoid accumulating down votes and close votes, here are some suggestions. First, get rid of the ALL CAPS in the title. Also, use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset the mathematics in your post. Finally, read about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) on ths site, with particular emphasis on how to [avoid "no-clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I's simple, really. First off, the polynomial $p(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n - 1} x^{n - 1} + \dotsb + a_0$ is said to be of degree $n$ if $n \ge 0$ and $a_n \ne 0$, and of degree $-\infty$ if $p(x) = 0$ (written $\deg(p) = n$). The last one makes some later results come out clean.

Now, if $\deg(p) = \deg(q) = n$, then it might happen that some of the leading terms cancel out when adding (e.g. $p(x) = 3 x^2 - 17$ and $q(x) = - 3 x^2 - 5 x + 93$). If they do not, the sum is of the same degree (no way a sum manufactures an $x^k$ with $k > n$). If the degrees are different, no cancelation can happen and the degree of the sum is the maximum of the degrees. To sum up, $\deg(p + q) \le \max(\deg(p), \deg(q))$, with strict equality whenever the degrees are different. You should check this also works if one of your polynomials is zero.

If you multiply $p$ and $q$, where $\deg(p) = m$ and $\deg(q) = n$, you see that the highest power of $x$ you'll get will always be $m n$, i.e, $\deg(p \cdot q) = \deg(p) \cdot \deg(q)$. Do check that the result also makes sense if one (or both) are the zero polynomial.